# Multithreading in a dll

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I wanted to make two functions running in the background at the same time inside dll so I did `CreateThread` in dllmain but it doesn't work. Any tips or help?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
std::cout << "Press enter?";
while (true) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x0D))
        Trainer(); Sleep(50);
}
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDll, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {
   switch (Reason) {

case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    MessageBox(0, "DllInject", "Injected", 0);
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, NULL, 0, NULL);
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;

}
return TRUE;
}
```

function example

```
void artemis()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(300);
        ammoArtemis = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create threads in `DllMain` (or do anything substantial, for that matter). It's a guarantee for a deadlock. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx): *"Because DLL notifications are serialized, entry-point functions should not attempt to communicate with other threads or processes. Deadlocks may occur as a result."* See also: [Some reasons not to do anything scary in your DllMain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?)p=40873

Comment: What happens and what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Where should i create one then? Thanks.

Comment: That rather depends on what you need one for. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for chaos in the text. I need two functions to run at the same time inside a dll and don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call CreateThread from DllMain because it might lead to deadlock. The set of function you can call from within DllMain is very limited. For details please read the article [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the thread, disable thread notifications for your DLL

```
DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDll)
```

That should help with the deadlock.

Your thread seems to start in the function named **main**. Thread start routines, however, need to use WINAPI calling convention and should accept one parameter.

```
DWORD WINAPI main(PVOID Parameter)
```

You provide the parameter value by the fourth parameter.